# WCF Client with ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have some simple WCF client code in C# on .NET 4.0
I made a service reference in Visual Studio and got app.config update that looks like this:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService2" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                messageEncoding="Text">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```

...some stuff...

```
<endpoint address="https://remote/remote.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService2"
contract="ApiRemoteService.IRemoteService"
name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemoteService2" />
```

This works fine:

```
var client = new reportClient();
client.DoSomething();
```

I then tried to do the same strictly in code and get an error:

> The message with Action 'DoSomething' cannot be processed at the
>   receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
>   This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions
>   between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between
>   the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the
>   same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,
>   e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Here is my code. What is different to the point where I would create a mismatch?

Thanks.

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,4,0);
            basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0 , 4 , 0 );
            basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0 , 4 , 0 );
            basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0 , 4 , 0 );
            basicHttpBinding.TextEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            basicHttpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            basicHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
            basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
            basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
            basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
            basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
            basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            var remotey = new EndpointAddress( "https://remote/remote.svc" );
            var client = new RemoteClient( basicHttpBinding , remotey );
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
            client.DoSomething();
```

Comment: The most common reason I've had for this message was a namespace discrepency.